# Opencv open 3d stereo video file and output to display

Tags: stereo-3d

is there anyone working on extracting the data from a 3d stereo video by using opencv? (e.g. 3d blu-ray). From some documentation, it stated .avi is the only supporting video file format on opencv. If there you are or you know, would you mind to give me a tutorial how to do that. (e.g.A frame of a 3d stereo video should be an image of 2 views plus one depth map? or A frame of a 3d stereo video is 2 images of 2 views and some depth maps?) How to read the information?

An other question is, is there any API in opencv can control the output from the graphic cards ports? I mean if I have a graphic card with two DVI ports, would it be possible for the monitor connected to A-DVI display the left-sided image of the 3d-stereo video while B-DVI display the right-sided image.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841485/reading-frames-from-video-file-using-opencv-and-native-code-c?noredirect=1#comment29556210_19841485

Comment: take a look at this to get an idea 3d film database http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/research/stereoseg/  . Apparently there is no real standard that the film producers use to encode the info. so it is a mess to extract the depth maps (i have not tried personally)